how to vmap over multiple Dense instances in flax model? trying to avoid looping over a list of Dense instances
from jax import random,vmap
from jax import numpy as jnp
import pprint

def f(s,layers,do,dx):
    x = jnp.zeros((do,dx))
    for i,layer in enumerate(layers):
        x=x.at[i].set( layer( s[i] ) )
    return x

class net(nn.Module):
    dx: int 
    do: int 
    def setup(self):
        self.layers = [ nn.Dense( self.dx, use_bias=False )
                        for _ in range(self.do) ]
    def __call__(self, s):
        x = vmap(f,in_axes=(0,None,None,None))(s,self.layers,self.do,self.dx)
        return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    seed = 123
    key = random.PRNGKey( seed )
    key,subkey = random.split( key )
    outer_batches = 4
    s_observations = 5 # AKA the inner batch
    x_features = 2
    s_features = 3
    s_shape = (outer_batches,s_observations, s_features)
    s = random.uniform( subkey, s_shape )

    key,subkey = random.split( key )    
    model = net(x_features,s_observations)
    p = model.init( subkey, s )
    x = model.apply( p, s )    

    params = p['params']
    pkernels = jnp.array([params[key]['kernel'] for key in params.keys()])
    x_=jnp.zeros((outer_batches,s_observations,x_features))
    
    g = vmap(vmap(lambda a,b: a@b),in_axes=(0,None))
    
    x_=g(s,pkernels)
    print('s shape:',s.shape)
    print('p shape:',pkernels.shape)
    print('x shape:',x.shape)
    print('x_ shape:',x_.shape)
    print('sum of difference:',jnp.sum(x-x_))


Hi. I need some "batch-specific" parameters in my model. Here, there is an "inner batch" of length do such that there is a flax.linen.Dense instance for each element in that batch. The outer batch just passes multiple data instances into those layers. I accomplish this by creating a list of flax.linen.Dense instances in the setup method. Then in the __call__ method, I iterate over those layers to fill up an array. This iteration is encapsulated in a function f, and that function is wrapped in jax.vmap.
I have also included some equivalent logic written as matrix multiplication (see the function g) to make it explicit what operation I was hoping to capture with this class.
I would like to replace the for-loop in the __call__ method with a call to jax.vmap. I ofc get an error when I pass a list to vmap, and I ofc get an error when I try to put multiple Dense instances in a jax array. Is there an alternative to using a list to contain my multiple Dense instances? A constraint is that I should be able to create an arbitrary number of Dense instances at the time of model initialization.

vmap can be used to map a single function over batches of data. You are attempting to use it to map multiple functions over batches of data, which it cannot do.

Updated answer based on updated question:
Since each layer is identical aside from the parameters fit to the input data, it sounds like what you want is to map a single dense layer against a batch of data. It might look something like this:
keys = vmap(random.fold_in, in_axes=(None, 0))(subkey, jnp.arange(s_observations))
model = nn.Dense(x_features, use_bias=False)
p = vmap(model.init, in_axes=(0, 1))(keys, s)
x = vmap(model.apply, in_axes=(0, 1), out_axes=1)(p, s)

pkernels = p['params']['kernel']
g = vmap(vmap(lambda a,b: a@b),in_axes=(0,None))
x_=g(s,pkernels)

print('sum of difference:',jnp.sum(x-x_))
# sum of difference: 0.0


Previous answer
In general, the fix would be to define a single parameterized layer that you can pass to vmap. In the example you gave, every layer is identical, and so to achieve the result you're looking for you could write something like this:
def f(s,layer,dx):
  return layer(s)

class net(nn.Module):
    dx: int 
    do: int 
    def setup(self):
        self.layer = nn.Dense( self.dx, use_bias=False )
    def __call__(self, s):
        x = vmap(f,in_axes=(0,None,None))(s,self.layer,self.dx)
        return x

If you had different parameterization per layer, then you could achieve this within vmap by passing those parameters to vmap as well.

In my provided example, there is a Dense instance for each of the elements in this inner batch of size s_observations each with different parameters. Though these are of the same class, they do not have the same parameter values. I will need to process the data in these batches with some additional layers or operations also with independent parameters. It would be useful to implement as a single processing pipeline over which I could vectorize my data. Perhaps my mistake here is relying on the Dense instance rather than instantiating a parameter array and vectorizing over the appropriate dim

I'm not sure I understand: in the example you gave, every layer is defined as nn.Dense(self.dx, use_bias=False) with self.dx a constant across layers. Where are the differing parameters defined?

Hi this is a question about how to configure these flax objects to exploit autovectorization as provided by jax.vmap; not a question about how to use vmap. The flax.linen.Dense instances each contain an attribute that are machine learning model parameters, and those machine learning model parameters are specific to those Dense instances. Thus, each of the the calls to the __call__ method of those Dense instances will operate on the input s[:,i] and the parameters hidden inside each Dense instance.

Sure, I understand that. But your example code has none of it, so it makes your question hard to answer because a core piece is purely hypothetical. Perhaps you can update your code to show how your layers are parameterized? The answer  to your question will depend on those details.

Hi. (1) I found/fixed an error in the function f such that the variable x was not actually filled up :facepalm:. (2) I have included some additional logic at the bottom of the script that rewrites the model parameters and rewrites the entire net class as matrix multiplication. Hopefully this makes the structure of my problem less hypothetical.
My intent was to rewrite my model using these flax Dense instances to make it more approachable to a general audience, but this conversation makes me think that these Dense instances do not make communication easier.

I see the updated code: I don't think it changes my answer. Every layer in layers is identical, so rather than iterating over them, you can create a single layer and vmap over it. In the cases where the layers are different, you should include the different parameters in the vmap. If you show an example where each layer has different parameters, I could show an example of how to do that.

if you add the line print(p) to the end of the script, it will show you the different values.
